# PingFederate , testing html adapter

Tags: ping, pingfederate

So I've set up ping federate as my IDP and connected it to my data store. But when I go to my entity url or my home url, I get a 404...

1. I've verified the port is listening.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to test HTML Form IdP Adapter is to configure an SP Connector. If you are just setting up the server, the most simple method is to just map the HTML Form as an IdP Adapter in the SP Connection configuration. Another key to a simple configuration for the SP Connection is to setup an ACS URL to something like https://posttestserver.com/post.php  (POST).  This is a cloud site that will receive the SAML assertion and you can view it.  Once the SP Connector is configured, copy the IdP-Initiated SSO URL from the configuration and put that into the web browser.